# Computing a two-dimensional integral (vector fields)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, vector-fields

this is a pretty basic problem, but how do you compute an integral over a vector $\vec{r}=\left({x,y}\right)$? Using this as an example:$$\int_{\vec{r_1}}^{\vec{r_2}}(x,xy^2)\cdot d\vec{r}$$
I‘m aware that $$\int_{\vec{r_1}}^{\vec{r_2}}(x,xy^2)\cdot d\vec{r}=\left(\int_{\vec{r_1}}^\vec{r_2}x\cdot d\vec{r},\int_{\vec{r_1}}^\vec{r_2}xy^2\cdot d\vec{r}\right),$$ but I don’t know how to continue and how to integrate over $\vec{r}$, since there‘s two variables involved I can integrate over.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't recognize that form of integral. What quantity is it supposed to measure?

Comment: I am aware that $(x,xy^2)\cdot d\vec{r}$ must be a scalar product between two vectors. What is the right hand side of your second equation ? Do you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Definition_2) instead ?